# Automatically ban user's IP on ftp brute force

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

Looking for module which will put ProFTPD brute-forcing ip address into hosts.deny. Say if 3 times password was incorrect, ban it from server, preventing to try other services.

Comment: I suggest you look at doing this at the firewall level for any service, rather than just for FTP.

Answer (score 7):

If your not adverse to installing other tools than you could use something like [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Features)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ban.html

```
  MaxLoginAttempts 1

  <IfModule mod_ban.c>
    BanEngine on
    BanLog /var/log/proftpd/ban.log
    BanTable /var/data//proftpd/ban.tab

    # If the same client reaches the MaxLoginAttempts limit 2 times
    # within 10 minutes, automatically add a ban for that client that
    # will expire after one hour.
    BanOnEvent MaxLoginAttempts 2/00:10:00 01:00:00

    # Allow the FTP admin to manually add/remove bans
    BanControlsACLs all allow user ftpadm
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: This will not block ip address from connection, hence there is a risk that attacker will try brute-force another services. That's why I was looking for some way to block his ip from connecting to server at all.

Comment: Sorry I misread your querstion. Have a look at http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/block_brute_force_attacks_with_iptables/ and http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/using-fail2ban-to-prevent-brute-force-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` [can do this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187) without the need to install any additional software, or reconfigure underlying services.

Comment: iptables doesn't checks for wrong logins on logs. fail2ban it's a service which checks logs and if it detects several wrong logins it will apply an iptables rule to lock that IP away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try BFD which works with both APF and CSF.

See [this](http://corpocrat.com/2010/01/02/preventing-brute-force-attacks-on-ftp-server/) for an example scenario.